# Is it OK to force the size of a bool to 1 in a C struct?

Tags: c, struct, boolean

I have a C struct with 8 boolean variables that I want to be packed in 1 byte.

This how I define the struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    bool a : 1;
    bool b : 1; 
    bool c : 1; 
    bool d : 1; 
    bool e : 1; 
    bool f : 1; 
    bool g : 1; 
    bool h : 1; 
} test_struct;
```

Then I would like to be sure it's OK to set values:

```
test_struct my_struct = { 0 };
my_struct.e = true;
```

...and do test like this:

```
if (my_struct.e)
    // do something
```

Will all compilers provide the expected result, i.e. use one bit to store the bool values?

Comment: I think it depends on compiler, but why dont you use uint8_t and bitmasks?

Comment: if `bool` is a typedef for `_Bool`, then this should work fine: c11 draft standard n1570: *6.2.5 Types 2 An object declared as type _Bool is large enough to store the values 0 and 1. [...] 6 [...] The type
_Bool and the unsigned integer types that correspond to the standard signed integer
types are the standard unsigned integer types. [...]*

Comment: If you're worried about different compilers "provid[ing] the expected result" because you need cross-compiler compatibility, you can't use bitfields since every compiler is allowed by the standard to implement them differently, with, for example, different sizes and different ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per C 2018 6.7.2.1 5, a bit-field may have type `_Bool`:

> A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of `_Bool`, `signed int`, `unsigned int`, or some other implementation-defined type…

Presuming the source includes `<stdbool.h>`, `bool` is `_Bool`, so the structure definition is okay.

Note that this:

```
test_struct my_struct = { 0 };
```

initializes all named members of the structure to zero. This is a result of the specification of initializers; it does not have anything to do with whether the bit-fields are packed into a single byte or not.

> Will all compilers provide the expected result, i.e. use one bit to store the bool values?

Yes, the C standard requires C implementations to pack bit-fields as long as they fit in the addressable storage unit the implementation chooses to use for bit-fields, in C 6.7.2.1 11:

> … If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit…

So, if you have consecutive one-bit bit-fields that fit within a byte (which must be at least eight bits), and are not preceded by other bit-fields, they must be packed into one byte.

Answer (score 3):

Using a bool bitfield for the sake of storing a number of flags at unknown places in memory is actually about the only safe and portable use of bit-fields.

> Will all compilers provide the expected result, i.e. use one bit to store the bool values?

Yes. `bool`/`_Bool` is a standardized type for bit-fields and the code you have posted is guaranteed to behave the same across compilers.

However, massive problems arrive as soon as you start to assume allocation order. For example `*(uint8_t*)&my_struct` could literally result in anything. You can't portably assume where the individual booleans end up in memory.

A safer, cleaner and more portable way is to never use bit-fields, but to use bit-wise operators:

```
#define a (1u << 0)
#define b (1u << 1)
#define c (1u << 2)
...

uint8_t test = 0;
```

Then:

- Set a single bit: `test |= a`
- Clear a single bit: `test &= ~a`.
- Check if bit set `test & a`.

For larger types, this is even fully portable across different CPU endianess.

Comment: Note: "For larger types, this is even fully portable across different CPU endianess." --> •Clear a single bit:`test &= ~a` is a problem when `test` is wider than `unsigned`.  Perhaps `test |= a; test ^= a;` or other approaches?

Comment: @chux The portability refers to using bit shifts instead of bit-fields. The `~` operator is dangerous overall because of implicit promotions. Rugged code should always cast back to the intended type after `~` has been applied. But that's another story.

Comment: Hmmm, I thinking a cast is needed _before_ the '~` to insure extended width with wide types.  Aside from this minor corner, a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

The individual struct members here all refer to a single bit, and most compilers will pack these together. However, they are not required to; Nor is there a requirement for them to make the total size of the struct 8 bits; although again you can generally expect this to be the case on most platform/compiler combinations you're likely to care about. Code that relies on this is going to be *fairly* portable, but if you're looking for an absolute guarantee you won't find it in the C standard.

Comment: It is actually required that they are packed together if they are of the same type, for as long as there is room in the bit-field "storage unit". Which in turn is of unspecified size.

Comment: @Lundin Where do you find that? I've been looking it up in the C99 draft standard, where under `6.2.6.1` it says "The representations of all types are unspecified except as stated in this subclause." and subsequently _only_ defines the layout for bit fields of `unsigned char`. It does specify that the *values* of an `n` bit bitfield are represented by `n` bits, but that only imposes a _minimum_ size. Packing also isn't mentioned.

Comment: Look below declarations -> struct specifiers. C17 6.7.2.1/11 specifically.

Comment: "An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bitfield.
If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a
structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains,
whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is
implementation-defined. The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to
low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of the
addressable storage unit is unspecified."